# exim4 - replace recipient domain name, virtual domains

Tags: debian, virtualhost, exim

I'm tying to setup exim4 as MTA for multidomain host. All users and domains are virtual, stored in the database like that:

```
create table emails
(
domain varchar(200),
username varchar(200),
password varchar(200)
)
```

Mesages are stored in the maildirs:

```
directory = /var/spool/mail/$domain/$local_part
```

I have multiple domains, like private.tld, company1.tld and company2.tld.
I want to setup exim to handle company1 and company2 domains like company1, and want, as well, to handle subdomains, like www.private.tld as private.tld. And I need this to be performed for every user, without explicit aliases for each user.
As I understand, I need to make a kind of domain aliases, so I created the table:

```
create table domains_aliases
(
  source_domain varchar(300),
  replacement_domain varchar(300)
)
```

And added
`select source_domain from domains_aliases` to the MAIN_LOCAL_DOMAINS.
And now I'd like to write a rule with condition for domains, listed in this table, probably like that (not sure):

`condition=${lookup sql{select source_domain from domain_aliases where source_domain=${quote_sql:$domain}}{{yes}{no}}}`

And perform replacement then - change $domain to `select replacement_domain from domains_aliases where source_domain='${quote_sql:$domain}'`
I searched docs but did not find how to make this. Maybe some headers_rewrite? Cannot find this in the documentation, it's a bit unclear for me, please help.

Update: Just realized that it is possible to make driver=redirect for something like `select $loacl_part@replacement_domain from domain_aliases where source_domain=$domain`, but maybe there's a better way?

Comment: Exim doc contains specific examples for virtual domains, see chapter 50 (*some common configuration settings*) section 7 (*virtual domains*), for example. The net is also full of examples.

Comment: @grin could you pls show me one related to the question I asked?

Comment: http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-some_common_configuration_settings.html *7. virtual domains* show an example with *redirect*, or like in https://p5r.uk/blog/2002/virtual_domains.html

Comment: @grin Did you read the question? ))) well, nevermind, I already did it a long time ago as described in the question

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you want to set the domain to the appropriate domain for the server.  You are likely leaving the envelope domain set to the "qualify_domain" setting.  You may need to configure your server for virtual hosts.  (Users need to be in the appropriate domain alias file.)  I have the following router to handle virtual domains.

```
# This router handles aliasing using traditional /etc/aliases type files.
#
#### NB  You must ensure that /etc/exim/virutual/${domain} file exist
####
#### This works with the standard "name : destination" alias format

# Domain aliases
vdomain_aliases:
  debug_print = "R: vdomain_aliases for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = redirect
  allow_fail
  allow_defer
  domains = dsearch;/etc/exim4/virtual
  data = ${lookup{$local_part}lsearch*@{/etc/exim4/virtual/$domain}}
  qualify_preserve_domain
```